# Route to Same component with multiple Params

Tags: angular, angular5, angular2-routing, angular4-router

HTML Code

```
<button (click)='getEnv("env")'>environment</button>
<button (click)='getSchema("env","schema")'>schema</button>
<button (click)='getEvent("env","schema","event")'>event</button>
```

ROUTE FILE

```
export const ROUTES: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'home',pathMatch:"full" },
  //{ path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'example', component: ExampleComponent },
  { path: '**', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'home/:env', component: HomeComponent,pathMatch:'full' },
  { path: 'home/:env/:schema', component: HomeComponent,pathMatch:'full' },
  { path: 'home/:env/:schema/:event', component: HomeComponent,pathMatch:'full' }
```

TS CODE

```
export class HomeComponent {

  environment: string;
  schema: string;
  event: string;

  constructor(public tasksService: TasksService, private router: Router, private route: ActivatedRoute) {
    this.router.paramsInheritanceStrategy = 'emptyOnly';
    this.route.params.subscribe(p => {
      this.environment=p[0];
      this.schema=p[1],
      this.event=p[2]
    })
  }

  getEvent(_env: string, _schema: string, _event: string) {
    this.router.navigate(['home',_env,_schema,_event]);
  }
  getSchema(_env: string, _schema: string) {
    this.router.navigate(['home',_env, _schema]);
  }
  getEnv(_env: string) {
    this.router.navigate(['home',_env]);
  }

}
```

My objective is to route to HomeComponent with differnt Values and the url should look like

http://localhost:4200/#/home/env1   --> routes to HomeComponent with param value as env1

http://localhost:4200/#/home/env1/schema1   --> routes to HomeComponent with param value as env1, schema1

http://localhost:4200/#/home/env1/schema1/event1   --> routes to HomeComponent with param value as env1, schema1 & event1

I know i can use query parameters but the url will look like

http://localhost:4200/#/home?env=env1

http://localhost:4200/#/home?env=env1&schema=schema1

http://localhost:4200/#/home?env=env1&schema=schema1&event=event1

but i prefer the format

http://localhost:4200/#/home/env/schema/event

Is there any way to do like this?

Comment: Whats your problem here?  Your route config looks fine though.

Comment: Problem is I'm not getting the values as assigned in constructor. Constructor was called only once. In console i could see ` previous URL: http://localhost:4200/#/home/env
current URL:  http://localhost:4200/#/home/env/schema
**no window definitions match http://localhost:4200/#/home/env/schema**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the greedy path from the route list.

```
{ path: '**', component: HomeComponent },
```

The above matches all routes to all URLs. It is a wildcard match everything. It will be matched first before the routes listed after it.

Comment: this suggestion worked. in my code i have done  `this.environment=p[0];
      this.schema=p[1],
      this.event=p[2]` which need to be corrected with variable names. corrected code `this.environment=p['env'];
      this.schema=p['schema'];
      this.event=p['event'];`

Comment: Actually no need to remove `{ path: '**', component: HomeComponent },` just need to put it as last element of the array

Comment: @user2822362 that's fine if that's what you want but it's not a common practice.